# Firewall settings for Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, firewall

I try to execute a PHP script on my Linux debia 7-server. This server has a firewall. The PHP script has to execute a CURL to api.parse.com.
The PHP doesn't execute, I suppose due to firewall settings.
Can anyone tell me which firewall settings I need to set for accessing the api.parse.com